# Can Jmeter able to record JavaScript web page

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I am trying to record JS page using jmeter but nothing is recorded. Please help me

Can Jmeter able to record JavaScript web page

Answer (score 0):

JMeter can download the JS files as part of the requests but it wont execute it.
To make JMeter behave more like a browser that gets HTML, enable the Retrieve All Embedded Resources option in Advanced tab of HTTP Sampler.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter can record browser network activity in terms of [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

- If your JavaScript triggers network requests (you can double check it using "Network" tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)) - JMeter should be able to record it, if it doesn't - it means that your JMeter and/or browser configuration is wrong. Double check all the parameters or consider switching to [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)
- If your JavaScript doesn't generate any network calls you won't be able to test your application using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers, if you would like to do client-side performance testing: measure page rendering or scripts execution time - consider going for [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework